# Google Chrome + FireFox not loading custom fonts (access-control-allow-origin)

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts

I believe it was yesterday when my website's custom fonts ceased to function. Now, the fonts are only shown on Safari, while Chrome and Firefox throw access control allow origin errors to their respective consoles.
Chrome Error:

> `Access to font at 'https://blockheaddevdevdev--grify.repl.co/styles/font/wide.ttf' from origin 'https://blockheaddevdevdev.grify.repl.co' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Firefox Error:

> `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://blockheaddevdevdev--grify.repl.co/styles/font/wide.ttf. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).[Learn More]`

[Here is the font I am using](https://blockheaddevdevdev--grify.repl.co/styles/font/wide.ttf)
[Here is the CSS that applies the fonts to the page](https://blockheaddevdevdev.grify.repl.co/styles/font.css)
[Here is the page that should run these custom fonts](https://blockheaddevdevdev.grify.repl.co/a.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are importing your style.css from this domain: 
https://blockheaddevdevdev--grify.repl.co

```html
<link href="https://blockheaddevdevdev--grify.repl.co/styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and not: https://blockheaddevdevdev.grify.repl.co

Thats why you get an Cross-Origin Error.

If you fix the Link tag  you shouldnt get that error.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Comment: If anyone is looking at this for reference on their issue, this issue still occurs on the -- url (https://blockheaddevdevdev--grify.repl.co), but is fixed on the . url (https://blockheaddevdevdev.grify.repl.co) so ensure that you set the correct CNAME when sending to your domain

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the my url http://127.0.0.1/sitename/ into http://localhost/sitename/ and it worked

Comment: was it blocked by CORS? If not, this may be the wrong thread.